# Sum of two disk usage is 100% when copying huge data

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sata

I have two hard drives, both are 220MB/s write tested. However when copying huge files (no fragmentation) from one hard drive (external, usb3.2typeA on motherboard IO panel, 10Gb/s) to the other (internal, sata3, 6Gb/s) the speed is only around 110MB/s. I also noticed that in task manager, their usages are throttling between 30% to 70%, and an interesting fact is that despite throttling, the sum of their usages is always 100%. I suspect they're sharing some kind of bandwidth. Is there any way to let both hard drives reach 100% usage and 220MB/s speed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If those are Hdd (spinning disks) , they typically use write buffers to speed up short writes. Once the buffer is full, you hit the real speed of the disk: 110MB/s sounds nominal for a consumer hdd. To get a better answer you'll need to provide the exact models of your disks.

Comment: They are 220MB/s write tested, with content sized 2GB > cache. The models are WD Red Plus and HC550.